# What is the format of the received GCM payload

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently working with GCM in android. But when I print the bundle extras I get

```
{
      android_alert_title = Test,
      from = 12345678910,
      message = Hello world message,
      android.support.content.wakelockid = 1,
      collapse_key = do_not_collapse
}
```

But "=" symbol, Now customer is saying that this not a JSON format.

Can anyone help me in identifying the exact payload format received by the phone.

The GCM payload format is JSON or not?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17767237/1979347

Comment: The data in the bundle should not be assumed to be in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

android GCM payload message format is Bundle format